Characterizing the concave conjugate.
Can the following optimization to find the conjugate be analytically solved?
$$
\underset{\beta \in \Delta_m}{min} \langle \beta,y \rangle +\sum^{K}_{a=1}w_a \log \left(\prod^{M}_{i=1}(p_{a,i})^{\beta_i}+ \prod^{M}_{i=1}(1-p_{a,i})^{\beta_i} \right).
$$
Here $0< p_{a,i} <1$, for all $a \in [K], i \in [m]$ and $\Delta_m$ is the probability simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Further, $w \in \Delta_K$ is held fixed here and $y$ is a fixed dual vector.
